# Delete one record from MySQL with php

Tags: php, mysql

I made a database (php/mysql) with photos and descriptions. Everything works well. I can remove the entire record (4 pictures and descriptions) but do not know how to remove only one picture to remain eg 3. Thank you in advance for your help

[image]

delete.php

```
<?php

 // 2. Perform database query
    $id = $photo["id"];

    $safe_page_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $id);

    $query  = "DELETE FROM photographs ";
    $query .= "WHERE id = {$id} ";
    $query .= "LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection) == 1) {
        // Success
        $_SESSION["message"] = "product removed.";
        redirect_to("list_photos_46.php"); 
        echo "Success!";
    } else {
        // Failure
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Failure.";
        redirect_to("list_photos_46.php?page={$id}");
        die("Database query failed. " . mysqli_error($connection));
    }

?>
```

list_photos.php - deletes all pictures and descriptions

```
<td><a href="delete_photo_2.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($row['id']); ?>"onclick="return confirm('are you sure? ');">{Delete}</a></td>
```

Comment: What is the structure/schemata of your table(s)?

Comment: You mean you want to delete all records except one?

Comment: Do you have 4 pictures per record?

Comment: your query is ok what is the problem?

Comment: don't you have any other field for better reference? such as auto increment id...

Comment: You have escaped your user supplied string using the right method for a MySQL database - BUT THEN YOU THROW THE RESULT AWAY AND USE THE UNESCAPED VALUE! Then you re-use the unmodified value in a URL string!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand that you have 6 columns in tables

ID
Picture1
Picture2
Picture3
Picture4
description

When you delete any record Picture1,Picture2,Picture3,Picture4,description all are deleted. If you want to delete any one picture you can set that column to NULL. e.g picture3

```
$query  = "UPDATE photographs SET Picture3 = NULL WHERE id = {$id} ";
```

Or when you are inserting pictures, insert four records for four pictures. In this way you can deleted them with the query in your code

Answer (score 2):

```
 $query  = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id = {'$id'}";
```

Comment: This removes everything and I want to have deleted only one picture :) $query  = "DELETE FROM photographs ";
$query .= "WHERE id = {$id} ";
$query .= "LIMIT 1";

Answer (score 1):

you may need to use update query instead of delete query

```
$query  = "UPDATE  photographs SET filename ='NONE' where id=1";
```